# Calculate median of multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, median

In my worksheet, named "Sheet1", Column A through Column J, each column contains various values (so they all have different number of rows).

How to calculate median of these columns and put the calculated median in row9, and columns M through V?
I known how to store the calculated median into desired location but really not sure how to calculate median.

I know this can be solved just by using excel median function, but this is not what I am trying to do. I have over 10+worksheets, so a VBA would be the most efficient.

Comment: Would the [MEDIAN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MEDIAN-function-D0916313-4753-414C-8537-CE85BDD967D2) help with the calculation?

Comment: I guess I have figured it out by using WorksheetFunction.Median. Thanks still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to set M9 =MEDIAN(A2:A8) and have the A2:A8 set to the range you want.

Then just copy and paste that over to the other columns M9:V9. Excel will auto-change the columns to B,C,D, etc, and will fill in the info you want.

*Edit* for VBA:

Here is a quick and dirty VBA macro to apply them all:

```
Sub StacvQ()

    For SheetIndex = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(SheetIndex).Select
        Cells(9, 13).FormulaR1C1 = "=Median(R2C[-12]" & ":" & "R8C[-12])"
        Cells(9, 13).Copy
        Range(Cells(9, 13), Cells(9, 22)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Next SheetIndex

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is not very automatic though. I have 10+ worksheets so really a vba would be the best